# Pairwise Attracting Sequences Bounded Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We say that a pair of sequences {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} are pairwise attractive if there is a positive number $\rho<1$ such that $|x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}|<\rho |x_n-y_n|$

*Prove that a pairwise attracting sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ with $\{x_n\}$ bounded implies that $\{y_n\}$ is bounded.*

I'm struggling with this proof. I know that if $x_n$ is a bounded sequence then it's true that there exists some numbers $a,b$ such that $a\leq x_n \leq b$. But I'm having difficulty showing how this relates to the pairwise formula. Is there some other relation that I am missing regarding bounded sequences and relations between terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction, you find that $|x_{n}-y_{n}| \leq \rho^n |x_0-y_0| \to 0$ since $\rho < 1$.

Then $|y_n| \leq |y_n-x_n| + |x_n|$. For $n$ large the first term is at most $1$ and the second term is at most $B$ where $B$ is the bound on $(x_n)$.

Comment: Why is $|x_n - y_n|$ at most 1? Is it not possible that $|x_0-y_0|$ is very large?

Comment: We showed $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$, so for all large $n$, we must have $|x_n - y_n| \leq \epsilon$, for any fixed $\epsilon$, this is the definition of the limit existing.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused why that constitutes the term being at most 1. It makes sense to me that we can choose an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ though.

Comment: @SpiderCrawler. The definition of $\lim a_n = 0$ is *for any* $\epsilon > 0$ (take $\epsilon = 1$) there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ one has $|a_n| < \epsilon$. Thus, in your case, $|y_n-x_n| \leq 1$ for $n \geq N$. There are only finitely many $n < N$, so the maximum of all of all $|y_n - x_n|$ is still finite.